# Eclipse 2018 better javascript support

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse, I am using the Eclipse EE version as I am doing java web development with it but it seems that it's JavaScript support is very limited, e.g. I get some help for functions and for loops but that's about it.

Any way of making JavaScript support at least half decent? It doesn't even have support for `document` or `querySelector`

Comment: Did you try [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide) (which requires Node.js to be installed)?

Comment: Haven't heard of it friend, I do have node installed, I am installing the extension now, will give it a whirl and let you know

Comment: @howlger seems to have been installed however I don't see a difference, I created a js file inside of a maven web app but still seeing same old crappy support for js.  Maybe I need to modify something?

Comment: seems to be working with `open with generic editor` ! thanks!